# Setup page for phpMyAdmin not appearing but the domain is

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-ec2, setup, phpmyadmin

Relative newbie here...

EC2 instance installed, apache is running and can see the Test Page for the Apache server

I am following the instructions found on 
http://calebogden.com/wordpress-on-linux-in-the-amazon-cloud-with-mac 
(the mac portion was no problem as I have FileZila and PuTTY setup successfully to the instance)

The first step in the instructions call for installing phpMyAdmin -- everything went flawlessly until I went to view I can head over and configure my phpMyAdmin

When going to [MY_SERVER_IP] / phpmyadmin / setup / index.php I am getting a 404 for the page. I verified the full path visually within the server, it is legitimate and the index.php file exists on the server.

Tried using both the Public IP (setup through an Elastic IP) as well as the Public DNS without success.

When I go to the Public IP or Public DNS, the Apace test page is available...

Security group has been tested and is setup correctly (otherwise SSH,, FileZila and the Apache test page would not appear, correct?)

What do I look at next to see what is keeping the setup page for phpMyAdmin from appearing?

Comment: What are the permission settings on your phony admin folders?  Public?

Comment: apologies Brain, not following what you mean by phony admin folders...

Comment: Damned autocorrect...phpmyadmin folders (sorry).  Are they open to the public?

Comment: love those autocorrects...  sometimes :-)
performed a ls -l for permissions on phpmyadmin and got the following..
 >> drwxr-xr-x 10 phpmyadmin apache 4096 May 12 03:01 phpmyadmin <<  
Is a chmod needed for this?

Comment: found this https://gist.github.com/aronwoost/1105007 -- will give it a go, drills a bit deeper than the previously linked post...

Comment: the github was not helpful -- had me searching for files that exist but there's were in a different path altogether...  Looking at permissions for the phpMyAdmin folder, says apache instead of www... I believe this needs to be changed to www? if so how?

Comment: used this to change permissions 'sudo chown -R root:www /var/www/html/phpmyadmin' and now have the following permissions 'drwxr-xr-x 10 root www 4096 May 12 03:01 phpmyadmin' so that was one of my problems, as the setup for phpMyAdmin still does not appear...

Comment: OK... ADd something to this...  the 'phpmyAdmin.conf' file will kick in a syntax error saying allowed is not allowed here for 127.0.0.1... when I comment it out with a '#' appache restarts w/o a problem...  Is this system hosed?

Comment: The final comment from me is actually out-of-scope for this forum but it is what worked, and can allow me move on...

Answer (score 0):

As we couldn't find why this was being so funky, and as we haven't this site launched yet, we stopped the instance all together, dropped the volume, installed a new volume and moved forward. All is good, going to take a snapshot, and prepare the site for launching...  The only take away we see here is stick with one set of instructions -- we were bouncing between three. Also, develop documentation habits of what you are doing, journal like. Makes it a heck of a lot easier to back track once that 20/20 hindsight kicks in...